# how to find tables used in a view on sybase

Tags: sql, view, sybase, sap-ase

Am relatively new to sybase ASE and trying to find the tables used in a view kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sp_depends](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs68.htm) system procedure as below

```
exec sp_depends 'view name'
```